# React/JSX: Iterating through an object with key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, jsx

I have an object that I'm using to keep track of which checkboxes have been checked on a UI.

It looks something like this:

```
      checked: { key1: false, key2: false, key3: false, key4: false, key5: false, key6: false, key7: false, key8: false, key9: false, key10: false },
```

I need to be able iterate through this object and set certain values to true/false, depending on the behavior the user wants from the UI.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more elegant way to instantiate this?
2. How would I do this using the Object.entries method?

I'd like to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
let obj = {k1: false, k2: false, k3: false}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    obj.value = true;
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`);

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by set values to true/false depending on behavior? And it's probably more extensible to store key/value pairs in an array or a map than in distinct properties.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm working on a "select none" option for the checkboxes on a page. If a user clicks on "select none", I need to set all the items in the object to false. If a user clicks "select all", I need to set them all to true. If a user selects some of them, I need to update the boolean values of the key/value pairs in the object to reflect which are selected and which aren't. 

I've updated my question with my attempt at using Object.entries the way I need it to work.

Comment: what didn't work on your example?

Comment: @TomMendelson the result of console.log prints out all the key/value pairs with a `false` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to set all the values in the object to true, you can do something like this

```js
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = true);
```

`Object.keys` will return all the keys in that object in an array. By looping over that array and then using `obj[key]` we can access each key of the object and set it to true

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions -

1. This is a pretty good way to store multiple checked booleans, as you can access them using object destructuring like `const { key1, key2, ... } = checked` which, IMHO makes the code more readable.
2. Try -

```js
Object.entries(obj).forEach([key, value] => {
  // Set obj key/value
  obj[key] = true  // or use value here
})
```

Refer -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries